# Jssor Grid Slider - How to auto-refresh images

Tags: image, grid, slider, refresh, jssor

How can I auto-refresh images on changing slides in the Jssor Grid Slider.

I'm using this to view surveillance images which needs to update every 5 mins.

There are multiple locations and a number of cameras in each location. So I intend to display 5 locations with each having 5-8 cameras.

Comment: Did you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd remove all child sliders.
And then populate html code of child sliders and then initialize child sliders.

```
        $.each(nestedSliders, function (nestedSlider) {    //This statements is not needed if $AutoPlay is false.
            nestedSlider.$Pause()
        });

        nestedSliders = [];

        $.each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container", "sliderh3_container", "sliderh4_container", "sliderh5_container"], function (index, value) {
            $("#" + value).remove();    //remove child slider

            //do something to populate html code

            var sliderhOptions = ...;
            var jssor_sliderh = new $JssorSlider$(value, sliderhOptions);   //reinitialize child slider

            nestedSliders.push(jssor_sliderh);

        });
```